# Different line break mode for an NSTextFieldCell and its expansion tooltip

Tags: macos, cocoa

How do I set the line break mode of an `NSTextFieldCell` to be `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` and the line break mode of its expansion tooltip to be `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`?

Comment: cellView.toolTip = [yourarray objectAtIndex:row];
[cellView setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

Comment: Are you talking about `NSTableCellView`? I am using a cell-based table view which doesn't have such a thing as `NSTableCellView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the below delegate method for the tooltip:-

```
– tableView:toolTipForCell:rect:tableColumn:row:mouseLocation:
```

And for the line break mode you can set to the xib as well.

```
Attribute Inspector->Line Break-> WordWrap
```

Comment: The expansion tooltip will be displayed automatically when mouse over if the text in the cell is truncated, without implementing `tableView:toolTipForCell:rect:tableColumn:row:mouseLocation:`. The problem is that, the tooltip will use the same line break mode as that of the cell itself.